# DLL reference including all namespaces?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, namespaces

I've got a project that outputs a Class Library (.DLL) - but I'm running into a problem where it's only exporting info on classes defined in the default namespace.  Is there any way to tell VisualStudio to output all namespaces into the DLL, instead of just the default?

The project has a Default Namespace of 'CALWrap'.  Then, there's basically the equivalent of:

```
namespace CALWrap
{
    public class CALContentManager : ContentManager {}
}

// ... meanwhile, in a linked .cs file elsewhere in the code:

namespace Common
{
    public class ContentManager {}
}
```

My problem is, I need Common.ContentManager to also be exported when I build the DLL, but because it's in a different namespace, it's not included in the DLL: when I reference the DLL in a separate project, I can't access that class.

Comment: `ContentManager` and `CALContentManager` are part of the same DLL ?

Comment: Not sure how to answer.  The project that's generating the DLL has .cs code for both classes.  I'm assuming that ContentManager is somewhere in the DLL output file, but that it's not exposed/visible?  I tried doing a test where in one of the main .cs files, I created a new namespace and created a test class.  Wasn't accessible when referenced by another VS project.  When I changed the namespace back to CALWrap, it was accessible.

Comment: Strange... did you try to access the class by using the namespace in which it is defined? example `Common.ContantManager`?

Comment: You know what, I think you might have nailed the problem.  I called my final .DLL "CALWrap".  So when I referenced it in the other project, I was foolishly typing in "CALWrap....", thinking I was referring to the DLL... but i was hitting the *namespace*, wasn't I?  I'm going to go back, and see if I can hit the namespace directly.

Comment: Yep.  That's the issue.  Chetan, do you want to post an answer so I can give you some points?

Comment: Thanks @Kevin. I just posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure both the classes `ContentManager` and `CALContentManager` are part of the the same DLL?

If they are part of the same DLL, you should be able to access them using appropriate namespaces.

Namespaces in an assembly need not to be the same as the assembly name.

Looks like you are trying to access `ContentManager` class from namespace `CALWrap` while you should try accessing it using namespace `Common`.

This should help you resolve your issue.